# "GameObject" not recognized

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started learning c# for unity today and at my 3rd line of code I run into a problem:
My VSCode doesn't "recognize" the `GameObject` variable. The autocomplete menu doesnt show it and if I hard-write it, it doesnt get coloured.
Im following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzq-DJeNIrU) and I dont wanna keep going without solving this.
Its worth clarifying that I didnt install anything other than *VSCode* and *Unity 2019.3.2* and maybe I need a some extension?

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 5;
    public float fhealth = 5.0;
    public GameObject player;
}
```

Comment: Did you install the VSCode Package via the PackageManager in Unity? Also see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)

Comment: use jetbrain raider , its better for C# and unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Code normally doesnt autocomplete Classes if not installed with Unity Package Manager. So, if you dont have any compiler errors you could just continue without autocomplete.